# Expression as an integral

Tags: integration, recreational-mathematics

In order to calculate the pension you can use this expression:

$\text{amount}(1+\dfrac{\text{rate}}{100})^y$ where $y$ is years.

Set $x=1+\dfrac{\text{rate}}{100}$ you count the amount of money saved over the years as follows: $$\text{amount}\times(x^{y}+x^{y-1}+...+x^0)$$

How can the last expression be rewritten as an integral?

Comment: I think that this can only be written as a Reimann sum with an interval from $[0, y]$

Comment: Yeah, I thought so myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think that can be written only in the form of a sum:
amount* summation from 0 to y of x^n
Integral would be possible only when there were very small values added each step.